# scikit-learn CountVectorizer UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have the following code snippet where I'm trying to list the term frequencies, where `first_text` and `second_text` are `.tex` documents:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
training_documents = (first_text, second_text)  
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit_transform(training_documents)
print "Vocabulary:", vectorizer.vocabulary
```

When I run the script, I get the following:

```
File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    vectorizer.fit_transform(training_documents)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 817, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 752, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 238, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 115, in decode
    doc = doc.decode(self.encoding, self.decode_error)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa2 in position 200086: invalid start byte
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can work out what the encoding of your documents is (maybe they are `latin-1`) you can pass this to `CountVectorizer` with

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(encoding='latin-1')
```

Otherwise you can just skip the tokens containing the problematic bytes with

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(decode_error='ignore')
```